# Displaying Meetup members via API

Tags: javascript, json, meetup

I'm attempting to display a list of members of a Meetup group, using their API, see https://api.meetup.com/2/profiles?&sign=true&photo-host=public&group_urlname=pipeline-marketing&page=20.

Specifically I'm trying to display the profile photos of all the members of this specific group in HTML. I tried modifying some code found at http://www.jquerybyexample.net/2013/04/how-to-display-load-images-from-json-file-jquery.html but am having some difficulties. The page is blank. I'm not running it locally.

What am I doing wrong?

```
<div id="members"></div>
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
  var memberURL = "https://api.meetup.com/2/profiles?&sign=true&photo-host=public&group_urlname=pipeline-marketing&page=20";
  $.getJSON(memberURL, function (json)
  {
    var imgList= "";
    $.each(json.results, function () {
      imgList += '<li><img src= "' + this.photo_url + '"></li>';
    });
   $('#members').append(imgList);
  });
});
</script>
```

Thank you!